# add a field in array with space in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I have an array with some existing fields and I need to add a few new fields in that array, below is working

```
myArray.myNewField1 = "someValue";
```

but I need that field's name should have spaces in between them or some special characters like space or #$% and so and I tried below and it showing some syntax error;

```
myArray.["myNew Field #1"] = "someValue";
```

Is it allowed to create any attributes names with special characters in Javascript?

Comment: Just remove the dot, it's as simple as `myArray["myNew Field #1"]`

Comment: As stated in one of the answers, this is an **object** not an array... don't get them confused as they're entirely different things

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, but in Objects, not arrays, just remove the `.` before the bracket :

```js
const myObj = {};

myObj["myNew Field #1"] = "someValue";

console.log(myObj);
```

Comment: I know the OP had `myArray` as the variable name, but I'd suggest changing it in your example to remove further confusion (especially as you do point out it's an object)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `.`:

```
myArray["myNew Field #1"] = "someValue";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myArray["myNew Field #1"] = "someValue";
```